Hierarchical Clustering with Large Datasets
I am currently aiming to perform hierarchical clustering for the purpose of customer segmentation. My dataset consists of 217,000 instances with 12-15 features. However, due to memory issues when calculating the distance matrix, my computer can only perform the clustering on ~50,000 instances. Therefore, I need to devise a workaround. I was considering the following options:

Performing k means clustering with k set to ~50,000, and then performing hierarchical clustering on these centroids (Given my data, the assumptions of k means are heavily violated, but I'm not sure if this will have much of an impact if the average cluster only contains 4 samples?).
Using a random sample of the 217,000 instances multiple times to see if the results remain relatively stable, and possible perform bootstrapping to compute 'average centroids'.
Perform some form of density based sampling using DBSCAN or the leader algorithm and performing hierarchical clustering on the results.

More info on my data: One of my features is approximately normal, another is Poisson distributed, a couple follow a lognormal distribution, and the rest are made of predominantly zero values with a positive skew. I do not wish to normalize or standardize my data, as the current scales roughly represent the importance of each feature.
Any recommendations or insights as to the best way to go forward with this? I'm open to novel solutions as well, anything would be appreciated!
